# Java: top-n elements from stream source

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Assume you read data items and associated scores from a "stream" source (i.e. no random access or multiple passes possible).

What is the best way of keeping, at any time, only those elements in memory with lowest weight encountered so far. I would be interested in the "Java" way of doing it, the shorter the idiom the better, rather than algorithm ("use search-tree, insert new element, delete biggest if size exceeded").

Below is the solution I came up with, however I find it a bit lengthy, also some behaviour might be unexpected (the same item with different scores is possibly kept multiple times, while the same item added with the same score is kept only once). I also feel there should be something existing for this.

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 * Stores the n smallest (by score) elements only.
 */
public class TopN<T extends Comparable<T>> {
  private TreeSet<Entry<T, Double>> elements;
  private int n;

  public TopN(int n) {
    this.n = n;
    this.elements = new TreeSet<Entry<T, Double>>(
        new Comparator<Entry<T, Double>>() {
          @Override
          public int compare(Entry<T, Double> o1, Entry<T, Double> o2) {
            if (o1.getValue() > o2.getValue()) return 1;
            if (o1.getValue() < o2.getValue()) return -1;
            return o1.getKey() == null ? 1 : o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey());
          }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Adds the element if the score is lower than the n-th smallest score.
   */
  public void add(T element, double score) {
    Entry<T, Double> keyVal = new SimpleEntry<T, Double>(element,score);
    elements.add(keyVal);
    if (elements.size() > n) {
      elements.pollLast();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Returns the elements with n smallest scores.
   */
  public TreeSet<Entry<T, Double>> get() {
    return elements;
  }
}
```

There is a similar question, but it doesn't include the stream source / memory requirement:
[Find top N elements in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084495/find-top-n-elements-in-an-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a "heap" datastructure. Java has a built in one: `PriorityQueue`. Simply define your comparator for "best", and feed all your data from the stream into the priority queue.

EDIT:

To add a bit more colour to this answer, you probably need to do something like this:

- Define a comparator that works the opposite way to what you want (i.e. favours the items you want to throw away) - or define one that works the right way, and wrap it with `Collections.reverseOrder(...)`
- Iterate over your data and put each element into the pqueue.
- With each insert, if the size of the pqueue is >n, use `poll()` to remove the "top" element from the heap - which, because of your comparator, will actually be the "worst" one.

What you're left with is a pqueue with n elements in which were the "least bad".

Comment: PriorityQueues are unbounded, I think he needs to keep only a certain number of elements in memory at a time.

Comment: Ah - I appear to have been writing my edit as you were writing your comment. See my edit.

Comment: It seems so indeed. pretty much the same solution he has but with a priority queue instead of a tree set.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to PriorityQueue, its a better choice than TreeSet as it keeps repeated items consistently in the top n.

Comment: In the case where n, the number of elements to retain, is much less than the size of the stream, once the algorithm has processed many multiples of n elements, most of those elements will be added only to be immediately removed, requiring two O(log N) operations. As an optimization, does it make sense to compare each incoming element to the value of the nth element in the queue and if it is less, skip to the next element in the stream? The value of the nth element should be maintained in the loop so the queue is only referenced when we know we have a qualifying item to add?

Answer (score 1):

You can guava's `Comparators` class to get the desired results. Please see a sample below, which gets top 5 numbers. Api can be found [here](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html).

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.common.collect.Comparators;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class TestComparator {

    @Test
    public void testTopN() {
        final List<Integer> numbers = Lists.newArrayList(1, 3, 8, 2, 6, 4, 7, 5, 9, 0);
        final Collector<Integer, ?, List<Integer>> collector = Comparators.greatest(5,
                Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder());
        final List<Integer> top = numbers.stream().collect(collector);
        System.out.println(top);
    }

}
```

**Output: [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]**