# How to find the biggest three numbers in an array java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of numbers and I need the **biggest of three number** with respective index value. I have an array like this:

```
int [] value = new int[5];
value[0] = 8;
value[1] = 3;
value[2] = 5;
value[3] = 2;
value[4] = 7;
```

How to find the largest numbers and their index values?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get a positive response here, it is best to show what you have tried.

Comment: your question is not clear.  Do you need to find the three biggest numbers or biggest of three numbers?  Also what is it that you say about the index?  Perhaps change your question to include example of the output.

Comment: And it's a trivial question either way, too.

Comment: Sort descending and then take the first three elements.

Comment: This is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084495/find-top-n-elements-in-an-array

Answer (score 10):

I suspsect this is homework, so I'm going to give some help, but not a full solution.

You need the biggest three numbers, as well as their index values?

Well, walk over the array, keeping track of the highest three numbers you have found so far. Also keep track of their index numbers.

You could start by doing this for only the biggest number and its index. That should be easy.
It takes two variables, e.g. `BiggestNumber` and `indexOfBiggestNumber`. Start with finding the biggest number (trivial), then add some code to remember it's index.

Once you have that, you can add some more code to keep track of the second biggest number and it's index as well.

After that, you do the same for the third biggest number.

Answer (score 3):

I have done it for you, and this works.

here goes the complete code:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

class tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] value = new int[5];
        value[0] = 8;
        value[1] = 3;
        value[2] = 5;
        value[3] = 2;
        value[4] = 7;
        int size = value.length;
        int[] temp = (int[]) value.clone();
        Arrays.sort(temp);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.println("value: " + temp[size - (i + 1)] +
                    " index " + getIndex(value, temp[size - (i + 1)]));
        }
    }

    static int getIndex(int[] value, int v) {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (value[i] == v) {
                temp = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Smart way ;) but not sure about its complexity

Answer (score 1):

**No need** to traverse through array and keep tracking of so many variables , you can take advantage of already implemented methods like below.

I would suggest to use a List of `Map.Entry<key,value >` `(where key=index and value=number)` and then implement `Comparator` interface with overridden `compare` method (to sort on values). Once you have implemented it just sort the list .

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] value = {5, 3, 12, 12, 7};
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int k = 0; k < value.length; k++)
        map.put(k, value[k]);

    List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> list =
            new LinkedList<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>(map.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(
                Entry<Integer, Integer> e1,
                Entry<Integer, Integer> e2) {
            return e2.getValue().compareTo(e1.getValue());
        }
    });

    for (Entry<Integer, Integer> lValue : list)
        System.out.println("value = " + lValue.getValue()
                + " , Index = " + lValue.getKey());
}
```

**Results:**

```
value = 12 , Index = 2
value = 12 , Index = 3
value = 7 , Index = 4
value = 5 , Index = 0
value = 3 , Index = 1
```

***By this approach you can get top N largest numbers with their index.***

Answer (score 0):

To get the three biggest, basically, you sort, and pick the last three entries.

Getting their indexes takes a little more work, but is definitely doable.  Simply bundle the number and its index together in a Comparable whose `compareTo` function only cares about the number.  Sort, get the last three items, and now you have each number *and* its index.

```
class IntWithIndex implements Comparable<IntWithIndex> {
    public int number, index;
    public IntWithIndex(number, index) {
        this.number = number;
        this.index  = index;
    }
    public int compareTo(IntWithIndex other) {
        return number - other.number;
    }
}

...
IntWithIndex iwi[] = new IntWithIndex[yourNumbers.length];
for (int i = 0; i < yourNumbers.length; ++i) {
    iwi[i] = new IntWithIndex(yourNumbers[i], i);
}
Arrays.sort(iwi);

int largest      = iwi[iwi.length - 1].number;
int largestIndex = iwi[iwi.length - 1].index;
// and so on
```

Answer (score -1):

Sort the array in descending order and show the first 3 element.

Comment: He also needs the index values.