# Most efficient way to get the largest 3 elements of an array using no comparisons but a procedure for ordering 5 elements descendantly

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have been given an array of elements and a  function which can sort 5 elements at a time.
How do I use only this function to obtain the largest 3 elements of the array with the least number of calls to this function?

The approach I have tried is dividing the array in groups of 5 each, applying the function on each group, and applying the function on the maximums obtained from each group.

This approach fails when the highest and second highest happen to be present in the same group.
Is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: [Find the largest three elements in an array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-largest-three-elements-in-an-array/)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-largest-three-elements-in-an-array/

Comment: Although this is an interesting question, Stackoverflow is not here to solve it for you. You need to show what you have already tried and where exactly you need help.

Comment: [Find top N elements in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084495/find-top-n-elements-in-an-array)

Comment: save any 3 elemnts element of your array into a 3-elemnts array so that your 3 elements are kept sorted and scan your original array and compare every element to the smallest of the 3 elemnts, if your current element is larger than it replace the smallest with it and re-sort the 3 elemnts

Comment: Thank you @blade, I think this is the approach. If you write an answer I'll upvote that.

Comment: This reminds me of the 3 fastest horses problem. This can help to understand and solve the problem: http://puzzles.nigelcoldwell.co.uk/fiftynine.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>


void sortThree(int res[3]) {
   for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      if(res[j] > res[j+1])
         std::swap(res[j], res[j+1]);
   }
   if(res[0] > res[1]) std::swap(res[0], res[1]); // second pass
}

bool lsearch(int src[], int n, int k) {
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(src[i] == k) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

void getThreeLargest(int arr[], int n, int res[3]) {
  res[0] = arr[0];
  res[1] = arr[1];
  res[2] = arr[2];
  sortThree(res);
  for(int i = 3; i < n; i++) {
    // if no repetition wanted
    // if(arr[i] > res[0] && !lsearch(res, 3, arr[i])) {
    if(arr[i] > res[0]) {
      res[0] = arr[i];
      sortThree(res);
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int arr[] = {91,21,3,-4,5,2,1,90,9,11};
  int res[3];
  getThreeLargest(arr, 10, res);
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    std::cout << res[i] << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Very simple solution here in a c-way to do it. You can easily convert it to Java. Scanning the array is O(n). Since the little array to be sorted and searched has only 3 elements we can easily use linear search to avoid repetition and sorting takes only 2 comparisons. It's still O(n).

Comment: There seems to be a slight bug in your code. When I use `int arr[] = { 2, 5, 5, 5 };`, I would expect 5, 5, 5, but I get 2, 5, 5. Your basic idea is valid.

Comment: let the asker fix it :P

Comment: The question is tagged with `java` - your code seems to be `C`

Comment: it is an easy conversion. I stated that in the answer. Just use the console print function of java, put in a class, change the way of declaring the array and you're done.

Comment: fixed it, i had to eliminate the lsearch since i stated it was assuming no repetition

Comment: This doesn't fulfill the question's criterion "I have been given an array of elements and an inbuilt function which can sort 5 elements at a time. How do I use **only this function**…".

Answer (score 4):

Since you have the built-in method to sort five elements I suggest: Sort the first five elements from the array. Repeatedly discard the two smallest of the five and replace with two more elements from the array (two elements that have not yet been considered), then sort the five again. In the end take the largest three of the five.

It will be possible to do a bit better than what I have sketched. Say you have 25 elements. For each group of 5 find the three largest. Then among the nos. 1 from each group find the three largest. The same for the nos. 2 from each group and the nos. 3. Now we can deduce that the three largest overall will be among the three largest nos. 1, the two largest nos. 2 and the single largest no. 3, that is six elements instead of 9. So we can find the three largest in just two more calls to your built-in method instead of three more calls. Generalizing the idea to any size of the original array will be complicated, though.

Comment: That is the answer I am leaning towards as well... but is it the most efficient?

Comment: No, it isn’t really the most efficient (I assume you are talking about run time). For the most efficient use the links I posted in comments, they will perform slightly better. But they don’t use your built-in method. This is O(n), however, which is the best big-O complexity you can hope for.

Answer (score 1):

How about this method.

1. Divide the array into groups of 5
2. Apply the provided sort method for each group of 5 elements
3. Get the first 3 elements from each array
4. Then merge the identified 3 elements in each group to one single array
5. Now repeat from step 1 to 4, until the final array size is less than or equal to 5
6. Get the first 3 elements from the final array

Comment: As far as I can tell it will be as efficient as my suggestion, no more, no less. I would consider it more complicated.

Comment: That I agree too. Noticed your comment later.

Comment: @OleV.V. I disagree with you. your alg would require n/2 calls to complete.  This one should be in some form of log(n). nice.

Comment: @Charles You will have to inspect all `n` elements in order to determine the three largest. This solution makes `n / 5` groups of 5, that alone takes O(n). More precisely both this suggestion and mine make `(n - 3) / 2` calls to the built-in method.

Comment: The n here isn't exactly the number of elements.  try it with an example with 10 elements. his alg can do it with 4 compares for the worst case.  you would need 8 compares no matter what.  This difference grows with larger sets.  Another way to thin about it is instead of 5 elements you can sort 6 at a time.  Then it starts to look like a binary tree traversal.3 lower numbers become your left node and 3 larger becomes the right.

Answer (score 0):

> How [to] use only [a function that orders 5(*k*) elements at a time] to obtain the largest 3(*t*) elements of [an] array with the least number of calls to this function?`

The sane method for *t*=3 and *k*=5 most likely is the one from the first paragraph of [Anonymous' answer](/a/52713548/3789665);
the improved one sketched in the second paragraph [*did* get convolved](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/288845/93149) when I tried to implement it - the saving grace being handling of *t ≥ k*.

If in addition to use of `orderK()` it is feasible to find the index of an element after application of `orderK()`, something close to *quickselect* should be best.
I failed to come up with a plausible rendition of *Hoare partition*;
something like this - close to *Lomuto* - should work:

```
    /** @return <b>absolute</b> index of <code>identifiable</code>
     *  in <code>a</code>, or <code>offset + k</code> for not found. */
    static <E> int indexOf(E[] a, int offset, int k, E identifiable) {
        for (int i = offset, limit = offset + k ; i < limit ; i++)
            if (a[i] == identifiable)  // identity, not equality/equals()
                return i;
        return offset + k;
    }
    /** @return an <code>int</code> such that according to <code>orderK</code>,
     *  all elements at indices smaller than the index returned are of
     *  values belonging not after the value at the index returned 
     *  and none at larger indices belongs before.</br>
     *  Use only <code>orderK</code> for comparison, 
     *  and identity to determine the index of an instance. */
    static <E> int partition(E[]some, final int low, final int high,
        int k_1, OrderK<E> orderK) {
        int k = (int) 4.2; k_1 = k - 1;
        assert 0 <= low;
        assert high <= some.length;
        assert k < high - low;
        orderK.apply(some, 0);
        int start = k/2;
        E pivot = some[k/2]; // [0, k/2] in right place
        E[] store = Arrays.copyOfRange(some, high-k_1, high);
        int found = start, end = high;
        for ( ; start < end - k_1 ; start = found) {
            orderK.apply(some, start);
            found = indexOf(some, start, k, pivot);
            if (found < start + k_1) {  // 
                int swap = start + k_1 - found;
                end -= swap;
                if (end <= found)
                    return found;
                System.arraycopy(some, end, store, 0, swap);
                System.arraycopy(some, found + 1, some, end, swap);
                System.arraycopy(store, 0, some, found + 1, swap);
            }
        }
        if (start > end - 1) {
            orderK.apply(some, end - k);
            return indexOf(some, end - k, k, pivot);
        }
        return found;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

int retmax(int *a,int n,int exc){

    int max = INT_MIN;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(a[i] > max && a[i] < exc)
           max = a[i];
    }

    return max;
}

int main(){

    int a[]={32,54,12,43,98,45,87};
    int size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

    int x = retmax(a,size,INT_MAX);
    int y = retmax(a,size,x);
    int z = retmax(a,size,y);

    printf("%d %d %d",x,y,z);
}
```

A simple O(n) solution.

Comment: You have *not* been given an array of integers. You don't know how to compare elements. You only know how to sort five elements at a time.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public class Solution {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
     int[] arr={7,18,92,72,29,57};   
     int first,second,third;
     
     first=second=third=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
     
     for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
       if(arr[i]>first){
         third=second;
         second=first;
         first=arr[i];
       }else if(arr[i]>second){
         third=second;
         second=arr[i];
       }else{
         third=arr[i];
       }
     }
     System.out.println(""+first+"\t"+second+"\t"+third);
   }
 }
```

Comment: You have _not_ been given an array of integers. You _don't know_ how to compare elements. You only know how to sort five elements at a time.