# Sort custom class arraybuffer and get subset in scala

Tags: java, scala, sorting, java-stream

I have an arraybuffer of custom object Employee which has empname, empno, joiningdate

I wanted to sort ArrayBuffer on joiningdate with desc order and get top 10

This is how I did but I think there can be a better alternative or optimized solution for the same

Cannot do the same in db query since i am using cassandra db where I cannot do the same for non cluster columns

```
val employeeList: mutable.Buffer[Employee]// getting from db

val employeeMap = employeeList.groupBy((p: Employee) => p.joiningdate)

val employeeDescSortedMap = new mutable.TreeMap[java.util.Date, 
mutable.Buffer[Employee]]()(Ordering.ordered[java.util.Date].reverse)

val limitedSizeEmployeeMap = new mutable.TreeMap[java.util.Date, mutable.Buffer[Employee]]()

var count: Long = 10

employeeDescSortedMap ++= employeeMap

    employeeDescSortedMap.foreach(employee => {
        if (count > 0) {
            limitedSizeEmployeeMap += employee
            count -= 1
        }
    })

limitedSizeEmployeeMap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in Scaladoc for methods with name including `sort`, you'll find [`sortBy`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/mutable/Buffer.html#sortBy[B](f:A=%3EB)(implicitord:scala.math.Ordering[B]):Repr). The only problem is how to use it to sort descending. You can either reverse the default `Ordering`:

```
val sorted = employeeList.sortBy(_.joiningdate)(Ordering[WhateverTheTypeOfJoiningDateIs].reverse)
sorted.take(10)
```

Or just sort ascending and take the last elements:

```
val sorted = employeeList.sortBy(_.joiningdate)    
sorted.takeRight(10).reverse
```

Use whichever you consider clearer.

Note `sortBy` doesn't sort in place (according to https://github.com/scala/collection-strawman/issues/25 Scala 2.13 was supposed to add methods for it, but I don't see them in https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/2.13.x/api/2.13.x/scala/math/Ordering.html). So doing `toArray` and sorting that in place will be faster.

There are also algorithms for top-N which don't require sorting the entire sequence, but they aren't available in the Scala or Java standard library, so far as I know. You can use [Guava's `Ordering`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html) or see [Find top N elements in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084495/find-top-n-elements-in-an-array) for other options.